# Map Activity zooms in every some seconds

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a map activity in my app, and I'm trying to make that when I open the map activity, it will zoom in automatically to my location but instead it zooms in every some seconds.

This is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String FIREBASE_URL="https://****.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase firebaseRef;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            final String title = marker.getTitle().toString();

            firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {
                        String event_title = user.child("event/event_title").getValue().toString();
                        if (title.equals(event_title)) {

                            String event_date = user.child("event/event_date").getValue().toString();
                            String event_content = user.child("event/event_content").getValue().toString();
                            String age_limit = user.child("event/age_limit").getValue().toString();
                            String event_hour = user.child("event/event_hour").getValue().toString();
                            String location_left = user.child("location_left").getValue().toString();
                            String location_right = user.child("location_right").getValue().toString();
                            final SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
                            final SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();

                            sedt.putString("event_title", event_title);
                            sedt.putString("event_date", event_date);
                            sedt.putString("event_content", event_content);
                            sedt.putString("age_limit", age_limit);
                            sedt.putString("event_hour", event_hour);
                            sedt.putString("location_left", location_left);
                            sedt.putString("location_right", location_right);
                            sedt.commit();

                        }

                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EventInfo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });



    return true;
        }
    });

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "You have to accept!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        if (mMap != null) {


            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {

                    CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()));
                    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);

                    mMap.moveCamera(center);
                    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap=googleMap;
    firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {


                String rightLocation = child.child("location_right").getValue().toString();
                String leftLocation = child.child("location_left").getValue().toString();

                double location_left = Double.parseDouble(leftLocation);
                double location_right = Double.parseDouble(rightLocation);
                String event_title = child.child("event/event_title").getValue().toString();
                LatLng cod = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(event_title));


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

}

I can guess that it is a problem in my `setUpMapIfNeeded()` method, but I can't find the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to below code

```
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);
                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

As onMyLocationChange listener is getting called when their is any change in location.

So if you required to change to center of map to latest location then you have do write code to check the actual displacement between previous location.

If actually displacement was happened then only you can change the center and zoom of the map.

Comment: Ok, so what can I change in my code to make it work?

Comment: remove this code.              mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {

                    CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()));
                    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);

                    mMap.moveCamera(center);
                    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
                }
            });